# Tweepy data is not appearing in JSON format

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I have been working with Tweepy for a while now. I have used their api.search as well as the stream and everything is working fine where I'm able to extract data fine.

When I started using api.lookup_users, my result aren't showing up in json but some other format where I can't extract data using:

```
tweet.text
```

or

```
tweet.username
```

This is my user lookup code that I'm using:

```
user_id = api.lookup_users(user_ids=[2198765],include_entities=['True'])

print(user_id)
```

This is a portion of the data that I'm obtaining from lookup_users:

```
[
User(profile_background_tile=False,
profile_location=None,
url='http: //t.co/7kRL5urm0d',
favourites_count=1262,
profile_text_color='000000',
notifications=False,
profile_background_image_url='http: //abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png',
followers_count=10356,
lang='en',
is_translation_enabled=False,
is_translator=False,
contributors_enabled=False,
default_profile=False,
entities={
    'url': {
        'urls': [
            {
```

I did run the validation through JSONValidator and as expected there's a whole bunch of errors.

```
Parse error on line 1:
[    User(profile_backgro
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', ']'
```

** Edit:

So I looked around some more and I found out that api.search will give results in `<class 'tweepy.models.Status'>` whereas api.lookup_users is in `<class 'tweepy.models.ResultSet'>`. Any idea on how to change that?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting list of `Model` instances. By looking at the code this behaviour can be easily overwritten by modifying `self.parser = kwargs.pop('parser', api.parser)` in `tweepy/binder.py` module.  You can provide different `parser` using configuration file.

Comment: I figured it had something with the parsing just wasn't sure how to fix it. I tried editing the lookup_users function itself but didn't work. So you're saying change `self.parser = parser or ModelParser()` to what you provided? Wouldn't that change it for all functions?